# Struts2 + Hibernate : No target setted for Hibernate Session object

Tags: database, hibernate, session, struts2, warnings

I use Struts2 + Hibernate. I get in my console this error : **No target setted for Hibernate Session object at /test - Method: xxxa.action.TestAction.testFunc(). Use the *hibernatePlugin.sessionTarget* property or the SessionTarget Annotation.**. Is it only a warning or an error? in both cases, what is required to do? Thank you.

Comment: what the console telling you? since when showing warning/error/exception on console it always tell you what exactly is the log level, else post complete stack tracke

Comment: It looks like you are using a library that you don't understand: http://code.google.com/p/administradordeedificios/source/browse/trunk/ejemplo/src/utilidades/SessionTransactionInjectorInterceptor.java?r=269 What is it you are actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Well, hello all. I am new in Struts2 and Hibernate, so of course I still dont understand much. But I guess maybe i should use two different packages in struts.xml : one extends "hibernate-default" and the other "struts-default", in the first i keep it for mappings and the second only for actions without contact with database.. am i right or wrong? thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've the same problem using Struts2 + Hibernate. Every part of the puzzle was ok, database, pojo class, fields,... finally I fixed this simply putting my java classes (DAO, Entity pojo class, Action class) **inside a package**, instead of a blank one.